# Is it too early to migrate from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3?

Tags: c#, .net, migrate, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-2.2

I'm want to upgrade my project to .Net Core 3.0, but when I'm looking at the migrate guide at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

I notice there might be libraries that aren't upgraded to 3.0 (especially the libraries that are discontinued are lacking replacement).

Following the migration guide mentioned earlier. Seems like the guide is skipping details about which libraries are being used in .Net Core 3.0

I'm getting a sense that I perhaps should wait for the guides and tutorials to be more complete.

Comment: It depends. When you do not need to upgrade don't do it!

Comment: Lots of the libraries in .Net Core 2.2 will be discontinued according to the migration guide, so the upgrade will force itself at some point.

Comment: This is really an opinion based question, there's no 'hard' answer. HAving said that, the one thing that isn't opinion based is whether the version is going to be supported. .NET Core 2.1 is on LTS, 3.0 isn't, and 3.1 will be LTS again. The rest is up to you.

Comment: How should **anyone** give a *correct* answer here that is not subjective? There´s no right or whrong here, which makes this question off-topic for Stack.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't touch an existent (working) project based on older frameworks, unless there is a very good reason to do it. Instead, I'd use the new framework for independent, brand new projects. When you'll realize the components you need are stable enough, then the upgrade process might be worthwhile.